# Webview loads url and then this image

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am trying to open in Webview webpages in same quality as it apears in normal browser. It is ok in most cases, but found one "special" url. Urls loads ok, but then after like 2 secons whole pageview is white with picture of play icon in circle. I can not click on it, just nothing. If I open this website in chrome and other browsers everything is just fine. Im not sure if it is not some kind of javascript, but JS is allowed in Webview.

Website is : https://www.auto.cz/volkswagen-polo-gti-zmena-jako-remen-87481

Image that appears is: https://ibb.co/yh7XPpJ

I have tried a lot of Webview settings but nothing helps. I thing it is causing small javascript ad which will pops-up in bottomside of page when url is opened in phone.

```java
WebSettings wsett = webviewVariable.getSettings();
       wsett.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       wsett.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
       wsett.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
       wsett.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
       wsett.setMinimumFontSize(1);
       wsett.setMinimumLogicalFontSize(1);
       wsett.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
       wsett.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
       wsett.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
       webviewVariable.loadUrl(url);
```

I would like to know what settings is missing.

Comment: try setting `webviewClient` and `webChromeClient`

Comment: I have tried this way, but it didnt help.     webviewVariable = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webovka);
webviewVariable.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                return false;
            }
        });
webviewVariable.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

Comment: You can try Chrome Remote debugger to try to figure out what's showing that image. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews?hl=es

Comment: try to check if this web view redirect you somewhere after it loaded and if it is, prevent it

Comment: One more thing: I tried to reproduce your bug, but it works as expected in my device (Samsung 9). Link loaded, not icon shown after 10 seconds. In which device/version of Android you see this bug?

Comment: @PeterStaranchuk thank you Peter, I am using 8.1 (API 27). I have used Chrome Remote debugger as advised here and it looks like it redirects Webview to somewhere to load "some" video - screen from CHRD here https://ibb.co/X7WTgNH   Thank you

Comment: Now I have found out it is not happening on Android with API 23. Weird.